# How to center the links in the very middle of the button/link?

Tags: html, css

Here is my work so far but I can't center the text of my links in the very middle. How do you do it? Thank you all!

http://jsbin.com/icafoq/1/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `line-height:40px` in this case. See the jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/icafoq/2/edit

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! So every time I want to vertically center the text in my navbar I have to add line-height property which must be the same as the height property of my button, right?

Comment: Great! And if my link has two lines?

Comment: You could do that but only if all your elements have 2 lines of text, if not you'll get something like this: http://jsbin.com/icafoq/7/edit

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it already. But if I give the .class property to that specific link/button with two lines and then a separate css, it should work right?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Love HTML and CSS. It's catchy :)

Comment: I notice you're new here, so here's a tip. If you are satisfied with an answer don't forget to accept it. Click on the checkmark under the up/downvotes :)

Comment: I did it 10 minutes ago. It said that I have to wait for 5 minutes but then nothing happened. I clicked it again right now and now it works! Thank you for your help!!!